# NullPointerException in Eclipse debug view right after connecting android device

Tags: android, linux, eclipse

I'm running Eclipse on Fedora 16 OS and I'm experiencing some strange problem. Everything works well until I'm not selecting debug view. After that if any android device is connected eclipse just stuck. I've launched Eclipse from terminal and found that this exception happens before stuck:

`Exception in thread "LogCat output receiver for ????????????" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiver$1.run(LogCatReceiver.java:100)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`

Is it any ideas how to deal with it?

**Update**:
Looks like I'm experiencing this issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34945.

Comment: Does running `adb` from a command prompt successfully connect to your device?

Comment: yes, there is no problem with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in eclipse https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384315#c11 and it's already fixed with last update